# Conditional validation based on column which may be nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am attempting to do a conditional validation in a active record model.

Basically, I am attempting is presence_of date should be there if the bill_due_amount is greater than zero else if `bill_due_amount== zero` then validation of date is not required.
right now I can think of this.

```
validates_presence_of :next_fup_date, :if => :check_due_amount_of_bill

def check_due_amount_of_bill
  self.bill_due_amount >= 1
end
```

I am getting the error as

> undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass

How exactly can I do this conditional validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `bill_due_amount` is `nil`. So in your method you have to check for `nil` first and then `>= 1`:

```
def check_due_amount_of_bill
  self.bill_due_amount.present? && self.bill_due_amount >= 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Thumbs up for the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

```
validates_presence_of :next_fup_date, :if => "bill_due_amount >= 1"
attr_accessor :bill_due_amount
```

(or)

```
validates_presence_of :next_fup_date, :if => :check_due_amount_of_bill
attr_accessor :bill_due_amount

def check_due_amount_of_bill
  bill_due_amount >= 1
end
```

You must specify the attr_accessor.

Comment: actually i had tried the first method but i did not do the `attr_accessor` so got stuck. Thanks and thumbs_up for the answer.